# How to download large size file using Hyperlink in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I am using multiple file upload control in update panel.I can upload large size file in folder. I am using hyperlink control to download file. I can download small size files using this hyperlink. but I can download large size files.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="file_upload" class="multi" runat="server" />
```

Hyperlink in Gridview :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Option" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<ItemTemplate>  
<asp:HyperLink ID="HlnkDownload" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("folder_path")%>'>Download</asp:HyperLink>

</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Web config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648"/>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Gridview code in c# :

```
        sqlconn.Open();
        da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select attachment_id,attachment_name, folder_path from b5_attachments where scan_id = " + sid + "", sqlconn);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        gvDetails.DataSource = ds;

        gvDetails.DataBind();
```

I got following Exception to download large file(50 MB).

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Result set :

[image]

Comment: it is very clear that can not find the file you try to give on the link, have nothing to do with asp.net

Comment: can you show us a record returned from your select query ?

Comment: I have added my result set above.@Thair

Comment: If you want to download a large file for viewing like a PDF or just binary content to save to a local computer - you may want to look into using a handler (**`.ashx`**)